# Facing abrupt crashes from visual studio 2015 and 2013

Tags: visual-studio, crash, visual-studio-2015

I am facing this issue for last few days. My Visual studio 2015 crashes abruptly. 
On checking the application event log, i found that for each crash, following log is entered in it.

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.24720.0, time stamp: 0x564ea97e
Faulting module name: MSWB7.dll, version: 10.0.14291.1001, time stamp: 0x56e7c254
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0000ed3a
Faulting process id: 0x1224
Faulting application start time: 0x01d18d0ac67af6bd
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSWB7.dll
Report Id: 6a7487d3-693c-4bd1-b48b-9b2262d8b27f
```

I tried to find about this

```
MSWB7.dll
```

. So far, I have only found out that it is a part of windows system and used as word breaker for the system.
First result on google for "MSWB7.dll" is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509108.aspx

My system has Windows 10 with Office 2016. I have all the updates installed for Windows, VS, Office etc.

I am unable to find any solution for this. Had lost quite many hours of work due to it too.

Please Help.
Thanks In Advance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Uninstall or disable the "Spell Checker" extension, if you have it installed, as it may be responsible.

Doing some Googling I see people are encountering near identical error logs with this extension in VS 2010 and later.  It appears this popular extension has become unstable in newer versions of Visual Studio, see Q&A section here:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7c8341f1-ebac-40c8-92c2-476db8d523ce/view/Reviews

If it's not that extension try disabling other extensions as it appears this kind of crash is often indicative of an extension that becomes incompatible with the newer versions of the IDE.

Comment: Thanks Jason. It worked. Never had any issue with spellchecker before. not even in vs 2013

Comment: You're welcome!

I love Windows 10 from an interface and general utility perspective, but I've long found VS to be memory hog and have some odd bugs and crashes... that's why I use Cygwin for my development along with full-fledged CentOS Linux for my heavier lifting.  Of course certain applications (e.g. C# XDA games) are much easier to compile in VS so I begrudgingly use it for that... but for general purpose local executables which doesn't use special Microsoft libraries, I recommend trying out Linux development or development in Cygwin (a Linux API layer for Windows).

Comment: Had the same problem, in addition I got the following exception in the Event Log: `Error Handler Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error reading from the pipe: Unrecognized error 109 (0x6d).`

Comment: wow! Been having crashing issues for a while - this fixed it.. thanks !!

Comment: I've been scratching my head over this for a while now, i used to get a few crashes a day when i reloaded a project after updating files via Source Control. I disabled the spell checker and so far so good. Thanks for figuring this out